# Errors compiling C program with time.h library

Tags: c

I am facing some problems in my raspberry Pi 3 B+ when I compile this simple program that uses time library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct timespec now;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

    printf("Nsecs %d \n", now.tv_nsec);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the compilation shows these errors/warnings:

> main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c: error: storage size of ‘now’ isn’t known struct **timespec** now;
>
> main.c: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] **clock_gettime**(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
>
> main.c: error: ‘CLOCK_REALTIME’ undeclared (first use in this function) clock_gettime(**CLOCK_REALTIME**, &now);

I verified that the struct `timespec`, the method `clock_gettime` and the constant `CLOCK_REALTIME` are available in time.h file.

I am compiling with gcc & C99. I am using NetBeans in a laptop to create the code and then I build on the raspberry (no problems so far in other projects). The command is:

```
gcc -c -g -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.c
```

What is happening? Could you help me to understand it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Pi specific question.  Could you edit your question and add the command you use to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of "clock" support isn't C99 but POSIX.

Try removing `-std=c99` from your compilation command and compile your code.

If that doesn't work, Add

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

to your code and compile it.

Refer this [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) for more details.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597685/storage-size-of-timespec-isnt-known?rq=1)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I will try it in my raspi and come back to mark it as correct if it works. thank you very much

Comment: For the record, it worked as soon as I changed in project Properties -> Build -> C Compiler -> C Standard to default value. When I had the error I used to have C99

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. As per the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) for `clock_gettime` you probably need to set a minimum value for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` in your code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now );
    printf( "Nsecs %d \n", now.tv_nsec );
    return 0;
  }
```

For completeness you may need to link against `librt` when compiling, but probably not on the Pi:

```
gcc -c -g -std=c99 -lrt ... -o .../main.o main.c
```

Note then you could set the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` value in your compile line if you prefer (using the `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`) but this is not recommended as it's not obvious from the source that it's required.

Answer (score -1):

- Raspberry Pi 3B
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Geany IDE

Had to cast now.tv_nsec to an unsigned int.
(unsigned int)now.tv_nsec

Run:
user1@rpi3b2:~/projects/general/hello_woild$ ./hello_woild
Nsecs 847355433

Comment: Thanks, but is not that. The problem is in the time.h imported items.

Comment: I do not understand this cryptic lines. What do you want to explain to solve the problem?